# Core data parent child relationship

Tags: core-data

I have a basic question regarding Core Data.

I have 2 tables one to many.

I have setup the app to add children to the parent, but I cannot understand how I set the relationship so that when I add a new child via a view controller that It adds the child to the correct parent.

I have generated the entity subclasses and have managed to get the app to add a child (but it adds it to index 0), but I cant seem to work a fetchrequest that finds the correct parent.

```
 - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]; 

 Child *newChild = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newChild setValue:self.childName.text forKey:@"childName"];
    [newChild setValue:self.born.text forKey:@"born"];


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ParentList" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    ParentList *parent = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0]; //this adds it to the first parentList in list at index 0 not to the correct parent
    NSLog(@"parent: %@ created", league);
    [parent addChildObject: newChild];

        //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        //////index path is wrong//////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////



}


NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parent's `objectID` to the second view controller (if I understood your setup correctly).
Fetch the parent (using `existingObjectWithID:error:` of the NSManagedObjectContext) in the other view context.
Set the child parent as the fetched object.

should look something like:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSManagedObjectID* parentID = //the parent object id you selected
Parent* parent = [context existingObjectWithID:parentID error:&error];
if (parent) { //parent exists
    Child *newChild = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Child" 
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newChild setValue:self.childName.text forKey:@"childName"];
    [newChild setValue:self.born.text forKey:@"born"];
    [newChild setValue:parent forKey:@"parent"];//Set the parent
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR:: error fetching parent: %@",error);
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the selected object id (assuming you are using a `NSFetchedReaultsController`):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Use object.objectID as the selected object id to pass to the other view controller
    //what ever you need to do with the object
}
```

Comment: I have come across the ObjectID before when reading tutorials, but I obviously need to read and learn more. To explain more, I have 2 table views that each have an input view controller that adds the parent and the child text. I am ok with entering the data into the parent, but I need to find the ObjectID that is selected on the parent and pass it to the child table view controller and then pass it to to the child text entry view controller. can you explain more on how i get the objectID from the parent selected row and pass it on via prepareforsegue?